# How to whitelist subdomains in apache or in symfony2

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, symfony

Lets say there are two domains one is `my.example.com` and `xyz.example.com` the `xyz.example.com` is invalid and when accessed it should redirect to 404. the `my.example.com` is valid and should redirect to the login page

now lets say its not just two subdomains its unrestricted number of subdomains which are allowed on `example.com` using the `* wildcard` character

how can i 'whitelist' certain subdomains to show login page (ofcourse after the user registers the subdomin its put in the whitelist) and the rest non-whitelisted subdomains to show 404 page.

can this be done with some apache configurations? some apache modules?
or if this can be achieved with symfony2.8 **without database interaction** that would do a world of good to my web application

when i said whitelist i just used the word to get my point across, im open to any kind of solution that is in good practice

Comment: So if not in a database, how / where are you storing the domains to whitelist?

Comment: i vaguely remember something about a config.xml file in apache that handles a list of allowed subdomains, so my thoughts is to write to that config.xml file as soon as a user registers a subdomain, so that apache can redirect the user based on its validity

Comment: Modifying Apache configs from PHP is definitely not the right way.

Comment: @dragoste true...legit true... what do i do now?

Comment: I would suggest to use database+cache (memecached or redis) and handle it in PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it either with **apache** or with **symfony**

## Apache:

**Two options:**

**1.** when you create a virtual host point it (in the vhost configuration file) to a 404 page

**2.** in your .htaccess file use the mod_rewrite rules to check the HOST and if it matches a pattern then point it to a 404 file

## Symfony:

Register a listener to all requests and check the request's HOST (in $_SERVER or $request->server) and if it matches a pattern -> point it to a 404 file

Comment: the thing is, there is no pattern to it, all subdomains are valid since im using the wildcard character, there needs to be a way to check if a subdomain is registered or not, so we need to look up the subdomain in list of some sort and if its present redirect to login else redirect to 404 page

Comment: then use the Symfony way. you can read the registered subdomains from the parameter.yml (or config.yml even better)